# Relationship between the latent heat of evaporation and $\Delta U_{sys}$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, phase-transition, gas

> A cylinder, with a weightless piston, has an internal diameter of $0.24 m$. The cylinder
> contains water and steam at $100
>  C$. It is situated in a constant temperature bath at
> $100
>  C$, Figure $2.1$. Atmospheric pressure is $1.01 × 10^5
>  Pa$. The steam in the cylinder
> occupies a length of $0.20 m$ and has a mass of $0.37 g$.(see diagram below).

> Determine the heat $Q_c$ produced in the cylinder if the piston is moved very slowly down a distance $0.10m$ (the work done on the system during this process has been worked out to be $W_{\text{on sys}}=-p_{atm}\Delta V>0$}).

---

Since the final temperature in the cylinder is $T_{f}=T_i=100C$, $dT=dU=0,$ then
$$Q_{\text{on sys}}=0-W_{\text{on sys}} \tag{1}$$
But this is, according to the mark scheme, incorrect and that $Q_{\text{on gas}}$ should be
$$Q=-\Delta U-W_{\text{on sys}}=L \Delta m-W_{\text{on sys}}=-8.7 \times 10J  $$
(heat transferred to the surrounding)
where $\Delta m=\frac{1}{2}(0.37\times10^{-3})$ and $L$ is the latent heat of evaporation of water.

Shouldn't $Q$ be $Q=\Delta U-W_{\text{on gas}}$ and I do not understand how $\Delta U=L\Delta m$ can hold, why is $\Delta U \neq0$?

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there is a change of phase at constant temperature, $\Delta U$ is not equal to zero.  At the same temperature, the internal energy of the vapor is higher than the internal energy of the liquid.

From the first law of thermodynamics, $$\Delta U=Q-P\Delta V$$ So, $$\Delta H=Q$$. But the latent heat of vaporization is considered the change in enthalpy per unit mass, not the change in internal energy.  So the solution you have been given by your teacher is incorrect.  The latent heat of vaporization already includes the $p\Delta V$ work.  So the correct answer should simply be $$Q=\Delta H=L\Delta m$$